# Weblogic not processing more info after StuckThread error

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

We have a WebLogic Server were multiple times there has been an error. Checking thru the internet one solution is to increase the value of the Max Stuck Thread but I'm not really convinced this will help, since I got no idea how long will take to unlock the thread.  Here is the error, I'm a bit confused (since I'm new to this) with the stack trace as to what exactly happened or find out what cause the stuck thread.

```
 <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "623" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 623465 ms
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
    sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.readInternal(NIOInputStream.java:146)
    weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.read(NIOInputStream.java:90)
    weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.read(NIOInputStream.java:73)
    weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.readFromNetwork(JSSEFilterImpl.java:496)
    weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.handleUnwrapResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:675)
    weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:554)
    weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:99)
    weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:78)
    weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:240)
    weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:574)
    weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:545)
    weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:236)
    weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:685)
    weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:41)
    weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1545)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:394)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
    com.naturgy.sgi.appclients.rest.gestionot.ClientOFSCRest.getOctetStreamBasicAuth(ClientOFSCRest.java:309)
    com.naturgy.sgi.appclients.rest.gestionot.ClientOFSCRest.getFirma(ClientOFSCRest.java:265)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
    com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
    org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy253.getFirma(Unknown Source)
    com.naturgy.sgi.appclients.rest.gestionot.ClientOFSCRest_81jy8c_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
    com.naturgy.sgi.appclients.rest.gestionot.ClientOFSCRest_81jy8c_NoIntfViewImpl.getFirma(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    com.naturgy.sgi.appclients.rest.gestionot.ClientOFSCRest$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getFirma(Unknown Source)
    com.naturgy.sgi.controller.gestionot.FirmasOFSCController.obtenerFirmaOFSCNoCheckEstadoEnvio(FirmasOFSCController.java:61)
    com.naturgy.sgi.controller.gestionot.FirmasOFSCController.obtenerFirmasOFSCListActIds(FirmasOFSCController.java:93)
    com.naturgy.sgi.controller.gestionot.FirmasOFSCController.obtenerFirmasOFSC(FirmasOFSCController.java:48)
    com.naturgy.sgi.schedules.gestionot.PlanificadorTareas.obtFirmasOTsOFSC(PlanificadorTareas.java:233)
    com.naturgy.sgi.schedules.gestionot.PlanificadorTareas.ejecucionSecuencial(PlanificadorTareas.java:245)
    com.naturgy.sgi.schedules.gestionot.PlanificadorTareas$$Lambda$47/1863387985.run(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.TaskWrapper.call(TaskWrapper.java:151)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.future.AbstractFutureImpl.runTask(AbstractFutureImpl.java:391)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.future.AbstractFutureImpl.doRun(AbstractFutureImpl.java:436)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.future.ManagedScheduledFutureImpl.timerExpired(ManagedScheduledFutureImpl.java:86)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.future.ManagedPeriodFutureImpl.timerExpired(ManagedPeriodFutureImpl.java:97)
    weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:290)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.future.ManagedScheduledFutureImpl.run(ManagedScheduledFutureImpl.java:96)
    weblogic.work.concurrent.ScheduledWorkManager$ScheduledWork.run(ScheduledWorkManager.java:174)
    weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

So far what we have been doing is restarting the managed service. We haven't found any CPU or Java Memory error in the logs of the webservice or the managed service log.

Comment: Could you analyse this method com.naturgy.sgi.appclients.rest.gestionot.ClientOFSCRest.getFirma? I think it calls another system, which is too slow.

Comment: Your application is calling an external REST service through http. This call seems to be be launched with a timer, not in response to an http request.
Your best option is to set a connection and read timeout at your jersey client to not let the thread wait for eternaly after an answser that will never come.